# How to deploy React + Laravel on AWS using RDS DB

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-8, amazon-rds

I know how to deploy separately laravel and react on AWS. How can I deploy them as one application? What are the services do I need to use on AWS? How could I connect my frontend and backend?

I launched an EC2 instance, deployed my frontend REACT code onto it. Any further guide how to proceed forward starting from deployment to connect it to my domain.